# WPF - getting the REAL width of a control

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, scroll, width

I want to set the `MinWidth` of a `Grid` `ColumnDefinitions` to the `ActualWidth` of a `DataGrid` inside it.

The main problem is the `DataGrid` has a (built-in) vertical scroller since its contents are many. So, the actual width is the size of its columns and some more, but not including the scroller.

What happens is that when I set the MinWidth, I get the rightmost column hidden behind the scroller.

I appreciate solving this both in the code and the XAML (just in order to learn).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `DataGrid` into a `Canvas` and bind to the `ActualWidth` property of that instead.